# Is there a way to change where I beam down to?

Tags: starbound

On Starbound, when ever you beam down to a planet, it drops you in the same spot each time. Is there a way to edit where it drops you (no mods preferably)?

I am exploring planets to find a good place to live, and it would be nice to be able to pick a place to build, instead of having to build relativly close to the spawn/teleport of the planet.